# LAN connection drop every couple of minute

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1, network-adapter

I have a problem related to my LAN. It drop every couple of minutes, only for my PC, so it's not network issues (wired), but PC issue.

Winx64 8.1 Pro.
ASUS p9x79 motherboard. (I use integrated ethernet port- cable is 1 m long)

I tried reinstalling the drivers, looking the events, scanning for malware, and various other things. nothing helped so far. I tried to look at the event viewer, but I always get the same message from something named WMI

SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE (TargetInstance ISA 'Msvm_ExternalEthernetPort') OR (TargetInstance ISA 'Msvm_VmLANEndpoint') OR (TargetInstance ISA 'Msvm_SyntheticEthernetPort') OR (TargetInstance ISA 'Msvm_ComputerSystem') OR (TargetInstance ISA 'Msvm_VLANEndpointSettingData')

Any suggestions how to get into the error and fix it, are welcome.

Comment: Some specifications would help. What is the make & model of your PC, and router. Also, are you using the on-board ethernet (built into the motherboard) or is it a PCI/PCIe card? If you don't know that's ok, usually if the ethernet port is right next to other ports USB or Audio, then that means it's on-board ethernet.

Comment: Also do try another ethernet cable just in case it is faulty.  I assume you're not exceeding the cable length limit?  100m is typical, depending on the CAT rating of the cable of course, but I've seen cables unable to cope with more than 50m.

Comment: see update ... 1 m of cable on the built in board. The router is fine

Comment: SYNC Timing Synchronization failure - Failed to acquire FEC f...

Comment: I get this on my router logs

Comment: "SYNC Timing Synchronization failure" has nothing to do with wired ethernet, that's modem-side stuff (the modem is the bit that talks to your ISP and provides you internet access).  Those router log entries may be unrelated to your issue.  Are you sure your your PC's ethernet conenction is dropping, or is it actually your Internet access that keeps dropping?

Comment: sure. I am unable to ping anything or reach the router

Comment: OK we should probably assume that the "SYNC Timing Synchronization failure" log entries are *unrelated* to your ethernet dropping issue.  Now I happen to know from experience that Intel 82579V ethernet adapters (which is what's on your motherboard) are a bit hit-and-miss.  I've had a couple of different PCs in my time, both with the 82579V, that dropped ethernet connections regularly.  So that's two out of about six PCs.  Maybe I was unlucky.  In both cases I purcahsed an intel PCI-e ethernet card and disabled on-board ethernet. Anyway, try new/different cable first and see how you go.

Comment: will do. Luckyly I have a ethernet card at work that I can test.